# Masstransit Saga is not triggered when event message arrives with proper correlation id

Tags: masstransit, saga

I have a Saga (ServiceA) that sends a command to a queue <queueA> that is consumed by ServiceB. ServiceB replies with an event which consumed by Saga and moves to another state. ServiceB performs along running operation and when it is done - publishes a message to a topic that Saga listens to.

It used to work fine but now I have a problem that the last message arrives at topic subscription, then it is forwarded to the Saga queue <queueA> and nothing happens. The Saga event is not triggered. Note: the Saga queue <queueA> is empty.

Here is Masstransit log when message is forwarded to the Saga queue:

EntityPath: <queueA>

Level: DEBUG

Logger: MassTransit

Message:  Receiving <correlationId>:<messageId>(<queueA>)

MessageId: <messageId>

ProcessId: 11111

SessionId: <correlationId>

ThreadId: 1

Time: 2022-03-29 10:07:52.4338

Masstransit log message that follows the previous one:

ConsumerType: <Saga instance type>

Duration: 00:00:00.1024322

 InputAddress: sb://no-host-configured/<queueA>

Level: DEBUG

 Logger: MassTransit

 Message: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object] RECEIVE sb://no-host-configured/   (00:00:00.1024322)

 MessageId: <messageId>

MessageType: <messsage data type>

 ProcessId: 11111

 ThreadId: 1

 Time: 2022-03-29 10:07:52.5432

Notice the "no-host-configured" part of address. I checked other logged messages and they are fine. what does this problem mean? tried to google but no luck so far.

Also, notice that <correlationId> is not specified in the last log message. it is supposed to be used to pick the right session. but it is not specified there.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Azure Service Bus is used as a broker and session id is set with the same value as correlation id

```
 await _endpoint.Publish(new EventMessage
                    {
                        //properties
                    }, publishContext =>
                    {
                        publishContext.CorrelationId = correlationId;
                        publishContext.SetSessionId(correlationId.Value.ToString());
                    });
```

UPDATE 2:
In order to publish an event message when long running operation is done - an instance of IPublishEndpoint is injected and CorrelationId and SessionId are set.

Comment: Is your saga using the message session saga repository? If so, SessionId would be required to load the saga state. Seems like your service might not be setting the SessionId when producing the message? Also, this reeks of Azure Functions, though you didn't specify anything in your question to that effect.

Comment: Chris, please see the update in the bottom of the post.

Comment: Chris, is there any way to investigate why we have "no-host-configured" part of address in log message? that shouldn't be like that, right?

Comment: Without actual bus/consumer configuration code, not really. the no-host-configured thing looks like an Azure Functions setup.